# replace text with part of text using regex with bash perl

Tags: bash, perl, regex

For example I have this output:

```
string1 anynameveryveryverylong string2
string1 othernameveryveryverylong   string2
```

I want truncate the name to the first ten characters:

```
string1 anynamever  string2
string1 othernamev  string2
```

a pseudo regex can be:

```
perl -pe "s/([^\t]+\t)([^\t]+)\t/\1\2{10}\t/g"
```

How do i get this?

Comment: Sorry if it is not but this sounds like a homework task.

Comment: In fact, even on another topic I was written. Instead of saying it looks like homework, to get me to improve my questions, tell me what I'm wrong, if it's not too difficult for you.

Comment: It has to be perl?

Comment: yes, I have adjusted now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/^(\S+\s+)(\S{10})\S*/$1$2/'
```

- `^` matches at the start of the string
- `\S` means non-whitespace
- `+` means *repeated at least once*
- `\s` means whitespace
- `{10}` means *repeated 10 times*

I.e. Keep the first word and the first 10 characters of the following word while forgetting the remaining characters of the second word.

Your pseudoregex has one substantial problem: the `{10}` is placed in the replacement part, but the replacement is just a string. The regex happens in the pattern part only.

Comment: From this solution born another problem. I want specifically tab. If I write this code: `perl -pe 's/^([^\t]+\t)([^\t]{10})\S*/\1\2\t/'` works, but if I change the last `\S*` in `\t`, in this manner `perl -pe 's/^([^\t]+\t)([^\t]{10})\t/\1\2\t/'` all doesn't work anymore, why?

Comment: Ok I have understand the logic: `perl -pe 's/^([^\t]+\t)([^\t]{10})[^\t]*/\1\2/'`

Comment: @MarioPalumbo: Use `$1` and `$2`, `\1` and `\2` only make sense in the pattern part.

Answer (score 3):

Some more choices:

1. Perl with autosplitting on tabs:

   ```
   $ perl -F"\t" -lae '$F[1]=substr($F[1],0,10); print join "\t",@F' file 
   string1  anynamever  string2
   string1  othernamev  string2
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   $ awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '{$2=substr($2,1,10)}1' file 
   string1  anynamever  string2
   string1  othernamev  string2
   ```
3. sed

   ```
   $ sed -E 's/(\S+\t\S{10})[^\t]+/\1/' file 
   string1  anynamever  string2
   string1  othernamev  string2
   ```
4. One more Perl

   ```
   $ perl -pe 's/(\S+\t\S{10})[^\t]+/\1/' file 
   string1  anynamever  string2
   string1  othernamev  string2
   ```